# How can you have a for loop iterate more than 2.17b times?

Tags: java

Consider my following code for finding the largest prime integer of the number 600851475143:

```
public class Three {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        int counter = 0, largePrime = 0;

        for (int i = 2; i <= 600851475143; i++){

            for(int x = 2; x < = i; x++){

                if(i %x == 0){

                    counter++;
                }
            }
                if (counter == 1){

                   // System.out.println(i);
                    largePrime=i;

                }

                counter=0;       
        }
        System.out.println(largePrime);
    }
}
```

Java cannot run this as this exceeds the int limit. I have also tried long, double, and BigInteger but to no avail. Is there a way to have a for loop iterate more than 2.17b times like this?

Comment: Use a `long` instead?

Comment: post the code where you used a long instead of an int.

Comment: I'd like to see some code where you tried a long

Comment: Read the section on [integer literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)...

Comment: my mistake was that I did not realize that I needed to put an L at the end for it to be considered long. My mistake.

Comment: Also if you're going to use the naive algorithm to find primes, you should at the least iterate until the square root of the number (i < sqrt(num))

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCOffee excuse my code, I am a beginner and am trying to learn coding properly and efficiently. You're right, this is extremely inefficient. Thanks for the tip. Any other feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Also  first ask `if(n%2 ==0){return n==2 //is prime}` and then in the loop `i<sqrt(num)` and incremeting `i+=2` considering i starts in 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java treats [a number without a type suffix as an integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10).  So, a value such as 600851475143 fails at compile time because it can't be identified as any sort of integer.

What you'll have to do is change it so that it reads as such:

```
for(long i = 2; i < 600851475143L; i++) {
    // code
}
```

The `L` at the end tells Java that this is a long literal.  Then, your loop will work.

Answer (score 1):

TRY BELOW

```
 long counter = 0,largePrime= 0;
          Long max=new Long("600851475143");

            for ( long i=2;i<=max.longValue();i++){

                for(int x=2;x<=i;x++){

                    if(i %x==0){

                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                    if (counter == 1){

                       // System.out.println(i);
                        largePrime=i;

                    }

                    counter=0;       
            }
            System.out.println(largePrime);
```

Comment: (or you could just put an `L` at the end of the literal)